# Передача сигнала через интерфейс

Tags: qt, интерфейс, сигналы-слоты, serial

Есть класс Device в котором необходимо отправить данные устройству через Serial Port и дождаться ответа устройства.

При превышении таймаута выходим из ожидания и отправляем соответствующее сообщение, если ответ пришел так же выходим и переходим в обработчик данных. Для этого реализовал нижеуказанный метод класса.

Проблема в том что QSerialPort подключается к классу Device через интерфейс и я не могу понять существует ли возможность пробросить сигнал readyRead от реализации интерфейса к классу Device?

Фактически у класса последовательного порта сигнал readyRead есть, но как его доставить не могу найти информацию

```
void Device::idleAnswer(){
    QTimer answerTimer;
    answerTimer.setSingleShot(true);
    QEventLoop loop;
    /*******( &_interface,&_interface::readyRead, &loop,    &QEventLoop::quit );  <- в идеале что то такое */
    connect( &answerTimer, &QTimer::timeout, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit );  //выход из ожидания если превышен таймаут
    answerTimer.start(200);
    loop.exec();

    if(answerTimer.isActive())
        //обработчик данных
    else
       //обработчик превышения таймаута
}
```

Интерфейс:

```
class I_phisicalConnect : public QObject { 
public:     
    virtual void sendData(QString data) = 0;       
    virtual int connect(QString _portName) = 0;     
    virtual int disconnect(QString _portName) = 0;     
    virtual QString getData(uint adress) = 0;     
    virtual QList <QString> getPorts() = 0;     
    virtual bool portAvailable() = 0; 
};
```

Вот схема архитектуры[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть мне нужно понять как пробросить сигнал от QSerialPort сквозь I_phisicalConnect до Device

Comment: Интерфейс ваш? Вы можете в него вносить дополнения, поскольку в данном виде он не пригоден для передачи сигнала от  QSerialPort в Device? я не очень понимаю зачем он вообще вам нужен, или в нем у вас находится таймер простоя, и/или ваш Device   от него наследуется?

Comment: Интерфейс мой, изменения вносить могу. Он нужен для того что есть несколько устройств с одинаковой логикой работы но с разными физическими интерфейсами поключения к пк. Для того что бы поцеплять нужный во время работы программы и хочу использовать интерфейсы

Answer (score 2):

Не надо делать connect в созданном классе. Это можно сделать только дикими костылями.

В общем и целом идея таких соединений:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В вашем интерфейсе:

```
// где-то (возможно в конструкторе) вы создаете ваш класс девайс
Device* deviceInstance = new Device();
connect(deviceInstance,SIGNAL(signalReadyRead()),this,SLOT(slotReadyRead())); // в interface.h должен быть объявлен сигнал signalReadyRead
```

и собственно прокинуть сигнал порта на сигнал самого себя в Device:

```
connect(port,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SIGNAL(signalReadyRead())); // в Device.h должен быть объявлен сигнал signalReadyRead
connect(port,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(slotReadyRead())); // здесь мы сами обработаем данные
```

В итоге: при появлении сигнала `readyRead` вашего порта, произойдет сигнал `readyRead` уже от вашего объекта, а в свою очередь к сигналу объекта уже подсоединен слот интерфейса `slotReadyRead`

Comment: Хм. Либо я вас не совсем понял, либо плохо задал вопрос. Интерфейс это который с виртуальными функциями. Вот 
`class I_phisicalConnect : public QObject{
public:
    virtual void sendData(QString data) = 0;
    virtual int connect(QString _portName) = 0;
    virtual int disconnect(QString _portName) = 0;
    virtual QString getData(uint adress) = 0;
    virtual QList <QString> getPorts() = 0;
    virtual bool portAvailable() = 0;
};`
Класс Device задействует методы интерфейса, а класс работы с портом реализует его методы.

Comment: тогда хотелось бы увидеть мвп. по нескольким строкам кода сложно помочь, тем более что никогда не пробовал прокидывать сигналы через pure virtual интерфейс

Comment: Да судя по отсутствию информации это вообще не практикуется. Но если не использовать сигнал readyRead, то как можно сделать реакцию классса Device на поступление данных в Serial? Вариант опрашивать по таймеру из класса Device кажется не очень рациональным

Comment: я надеюсь вы данные не по таймауту же читаете, а по readyRead. Там же в слоте делайте emit сигнала и ловите его в интерфейсе (или делайте коннект readyRead порта с сигналом, который потом в интерфейсе отловите)